# Entity inheritance with Doctrine in two separated Symfony bundles

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a project with two Symfony2 bundles. Let's call them *APIBundle*, which provide an API to access the database for customer, and *CustomBundle* which is an application that either uses the database directly or uses the API.

The *CustomBundle*, as it is an application, can depend on *APIBundle*. The opposite is not true.

In order to make specific SQL requests for *CustomBundle*, I wanted to create Doctrine repositories inside the *CustomBundle*. One clean way to do it could be using Doctrine inheritance by simply copying entities. This is what I have in mind:

**Interface**

```
namespace APIBundle\Entity\IEmployee;

interface IEmployee
{
  ... // Here I defined all getters/setters
}
```

**API Entity**

```
namespace APIBundle\Entity\Employee;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Employee implements IEmployee
{
   protected $id;
  // Some other attributes + getters/setters
}
```

**Custom Entity**

```
namespace CustomBundle\Entity\Employee;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="CustomBundle\Repository\EmployeeRepository")
 */
class Employee extends APIBundle\Entity\Employee
{
  // Empty - no duplication, everything is inherited
}
```

It worked until I regenerate the database, and the `doctrine:schema:create` command revealed me something I didn't expect:

> The table with name 'project.employee' already exists.

Yes, it's logical.
I have two entities for the same table, it tried to create it twice. The problem is I can't tell the command I just want to generate entities for just a single bundle. So, I looked for a way to tell Doctrine that these entities are the same.
Further researchs made me do this:

**API Entity**

```
namespace APIBundle\Entity\Employee;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"employee"="CustomBundle\Entity\Employee"})
 */
class Employee implements IEmployee
{
   protected $id;
  // Some other attributes and getter/setters
}
```

It works but I'm really uncomfortable with this solution for two reasons:

- I'm not sure whether these annotations were made for this usage or not;
- and, more importantly, *APIBundle* now depends on *CustomBundle*. I just can't keep it that way, otherwise I could have declared the *CustomBundle* repository inside the *APIBundle* entity, the result would have been the same.

**So, I've got two questions**:

1. Why the doctrine inheritance system make the parent class aware of its children? Conceptually, doesn't it break one of the inheritance principles?
2. In my current situation, what solution should I consider?

**Summary of the problem**:

- *APIBundle* must not be aware of *CustomBundle*.
- Specific SQL requests for *CustomBundle* must be in *CustomBundle*.
- Simple Doctrine inheritance don't work, because it's not possible to generate a fresh database anymore (`doctrine:schema:create` fails).
- SINGLE_TABLE Inheritance works, but it makes *APIBundle* depend on *CustomBundle*, which is not acceptable.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent, that the CustomBundle is using an entity and repository of the ApiBundle in its code? Since both classes are using the same table and, as I've understand your case, are actually the same type, single table inheritance is not needed here.

Comment: Yes. Actually, I want an exact copy of the API entity to generate a repository inside the CustomBundle, to write custom SQL command specific to the CustomBundle. The problem is, if I just do a simple inheritance, as it is in my first example, I cannot generate database anymore, because doctrine looks everywhere in the project and find the same table twice. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I wouldn't create 2 classes to map one table. That's redundant and you have to maintain that structure. Two bundles accessing the same resource is what you have to rethink, I guess. Maybe you can create a third bundle that is a bridge between ApiBundle and CustomBundle and don't let those two bundles know each other, but it rises the complexity too. CustomBundle sounds to me like some kind of API administration bundle which should be allowed to use ApiBundle repositories.